# BookshelfJS: all ints are being returned as strings [pg]

Tags: node.js, pg, bookshelf.js

`bool` seems to work as expected, as does `json` type (postgres), but all of my id cols populate as strings (breaking the front-end code)

Is there a way to a. fix it, or b. tell bookshelf that that field is an integer?

**Update**

By request, here's some code snippets. I'm just testing the waters with node/bookshelf, so this isn't complicated code; it's mostly right out of the getting started guide. The database is an existing one we've been using for 2ish years, the `id` cols are definitely `int` for all tables

One good example, Calendars and

```
var Appointment = bs.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'ec__appointments',
});

var Calendar = bs.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'ec__calendars',

    appointments: function() {
        return this.hasMany(Appointment, 'calendar_id');
    },
});
```

For this one, the calendar ids come down as `int`, but when I `fetch({withRelated:['appointments']})`, the `appointment.id` is a string.

```
{
  "calendars": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Default Calendar",
      "created_at": "2015-03-06T09:35:58.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-03-23T03:28:07.000Z",
      "appointments": [
        {
          "id": "107",
          "calendar_id": "2",
          "name": "Test",
          "starts_at": null,
          "ends_at": null,
          "created_at": "2015-05-29T23:13:20.000Z",
          "updated_at": "2015-05-29T23:13:20.000Z",
        },
```

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your code or your database, as Bookshelf.js returns integers for all my `id`s fields. Can you add the code you use in Bookshelf.js and the database scheme ?

Comment: DB is definitely `int`, code is just the boilerplate bookshelf `Model.extend` and `model.fetch().then(...)` and `model.fetch({withRelated:...}).then(...)`

Comment: that's really odd, I get number as well. Can you update your question and paste database structure, model, query and how you send the data to client?

Comment: Sure, I'm basically following the Bookshelf getting started guide, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem with the following code:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.types.setTypeParser(20, 'text', parseInt);
```

More details here: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/387